# Linking a .aspx file to an html frame

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html

So i'm going to make a website for a friend, and it's going to be in `ASP.NET`.
I'm going to have like an array of `frame`s that are going to be in the front like a 
couple of pages with a 3D effect, and are going to cycle with eachother.
The pages themselves are `.aspx` files, and I wondered if there's a way I could mix between an html `<frame>` and a `.aspx` file, possibly using ajax since the homepage is going to be some sort of a one page app, but there will also be more pages that will be shown in a `MasterPage` with a `ContentPlaceHolder` like a usual web page application in `ASP.NET`.

So if you have any insight on mixing an html frame with `.aspx` files, and also ideas and information about doing the 3D effects (I'm limited not to use `angular` tho, as I'm also mostly familiar with `jquery` more than anything), and I guess that means a lot of self-learn with `HTML5`, so like anything would help if it's on topic.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think you are asking way too many questions at once here. try focusing on one problem at a time.

Comment: I'm asking about the frame thing. Anything beyond it, about technical stuff with the design, is a bonus, since it's going to be a challenge for me since I'm familiar with mere web basics.

Comment: sounds like MVC is a better solution for u, why aspx files?

Comment: I'm following "orders" from the senior programmer. I'm given the design, and I need to get a website out of it.